# ShareThis widget padding is wrong

Tags: javascript, css, sharethis

I added a ShareThis widget to the right side of a page. One of the DIV's inside the widget has a padding style attribute set to 7px which causes the widget to look funny.

[image: ShareThisWidget]

When I change the padding to 0px  it looks fine(using chrome developer tool - the attribute can't be changed directly because it's an external component).
I thought it might be a conflict with one of the CSS files used but it's not (I tried taking them all off and it still happens). I also tried using the widget on a clean HTML page and it works ok, so it might be something to do with scripts being used on the page\master page, is there a way to check for conflicts?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of this or link to a page?

Comment: It's a bit problematic because i'm working locally and the pages are dynamic so it won't really give the whole picture. What specific info do you need?

Comment: the snippet of the CSS in question and the HTML of that part maybe useful. If at all possible.

Comment: This is the CSS: `#sthoverbuttons #sthoverbuttonsMain {
position: relative;
z-index: 1000000;
width: 30px;
padding: 7px;
}` and there is no HTML, it's created by the JS ShareThis uses (The CSS as well)

Comment: WHen you inspect the element with the padding the inspector should tell you what css file is causing it to have the 7px padding does it not?